# Excel merging and combining like cells

Tags: excel, merge

I have a simple excel spreadsheet that is a daily updated list of counters. The format of the sheet is as follows:

```
A         B          C             D          E
date      name       computer      info       counter
```

Example:

```
A             B          C         D              E
04/04/2012    John       186       Workstation    4813
04/04/2012    Mary       181       Workstation    2273
04/05/2012    John       186       Workstation    4822
04/05/2012    Mary       181       Workstation    2274
04/06/2012    John       186       Workstation    4854
04/06/2012    Mary       181       Workstation    2275
04/06/2012    Bill       183       Workstation    3698
```

and son on....

What I need to be able to do is combine all like cells. So for instance combine all of the rows for each month and subtract the last E column from the first one so it it would look like the following in a new sheet.

```
A             B          C         D              E
April 2012    John       186       Workstation    41
April 2012    Mary       181       Workstation    2
April 2012    Bill       183       Workstation    0
```

and so on for each one...keeping in mind this is updated daily and have many days, months and years.

I have no idea how to even think about doing this but I assume I would need a macro. If anyone has any assistance that would be great!

Comment: Are you tied to MS Excel?  This becomes a little easier if this were in a database, like MS Access.

Comment: Nah, you can do it using formulae. Check my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Assuming this is what you want to do]

I have spent some time on this, and it feels like I have finally got what you need. I would have uploaded a sample file, but file sharing sites are blocked here :).

Now I know, you want your output in a different tab, but bear with me on this for now.

The following solution is lengthy (expected because of the nature of your question). Follow what is done here to the T, and don't care about intermediate errors that might popup in some cells, it will all be sorted out in some time.

I am assuming your sheet looks like yellow part of the image. (Never mind the dates in the first column, they are all April 2012 dates, that's what matters.)

In cell F2, paste the following formula

`=IF(A2="","",MONTH(A2))`

In cell G2, paste the following formula,

`=IF(A2="","",YEAR(A2))`

In cell H2, paste the following formula,

`=IF(B2="","",B2&"|"&F2&"@"&G2)`

I am using the characters "|" and "@" here, because I am assuming they do not occur in any if the names!! **Please make sure if this is so!!**

Now copy cells F2 to H2, and paste them all the way down till wherever you have data.

Now, I am also assuming that you have 8000 rows of data. If you have more than 8000 rows, replace all '8000's in the following formulae with the number you desire.

In cell Q2, paste the following formula,

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($H$2:$H$8000,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($Q$1:Q1,$H$2:$H$8000),0))),"",INDEX($H$2:$H$8000,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($Q$1:Q1,$H$2:$H$8000),0)))`

**Please note that this is an array formula, and it needs to be entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter**. So in Q2, you paste this formula in the formula bar, and instead of pressing Enter, you press Ctrl + Shift + Enter. I have borrowed this formula from [here](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/).You may check out the site to see how this formula works.

Now, in the cell K2, paste the following formula

`=IF(OR(Q2=0,Q2=""),"",LEFT(Q2,FIND("|",Q2)-1))`

In the cell P2, paste the following formula

`=IF(OR(Q2=0,Q2=""),"",VALUE(RIGHT(Q2,LEN(Q2)-(FIND("@",Q2)))))`

In the cell O2, paste the following formula

`=IF(OR(Q2=0,Q2=""),"",VALUE(MID(Q2,FIND("|",Q2)+1,LEN(Q2)-LEN(K2)-LEN(P2)-2)))`

In the cell J2, paste the following formula

`=IF(OR(Q2=0,Q2=""),"",TEXT(DATE(P2,O2,1),"mmm yyyy"))`

In the cell L2, paste the following formula

`=IF(OR(Q2=0,Q2=""),"",INDEX($C$2:$C$8000,MATCH(K2,$B$2:$B$8000,0)))`

In the cell M2, paste the following formula

`=IF(OR(Q2=0,Q2=""),"",INDEX($D$2:$D$8000,MATCH(K2,$B$2:$B$8000,0)))`

In the cell N2, paste the following formula,

`=IF(OR(Q2=0,Q2=""),"",MAX(IF((($B$2:$B$8000=K2)*($F$2:$F$8000=O2)*($G$2:$G$8000=P2)),($E$2:$E$8000)))-MIN(IF((($B$2:$B$8000=K2)*($F$2:$F$8000=O2)*($G$2:$G$8000=P2)),($E$2:$E$8000))))`

**Again, please note that this is an array formula, and it needs to be entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter**. Make sure you have done all the steps above

Now select cells from J2 to Q2, copy them and paste them to as far as required. In the example screenshot, this would be upto row number 5 (to cover all possibilities).

You finally have the table you require. You may now link this table in other places using a simple 'equals to' relation. Also, you can hide all these extra columns from your data sheet if you so wish.

Whew!! I **really** hope that solved your problem!! I think I deserve a pat on the back for all this effort!! Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add 4 new columns (`F` to `I`) to your sheet and enter the following formulas:
(*assuming 100 rows of data: adjust as required!*)

```
F --> =DATE(YEAR(A1), MONTH(A1), 1)

G --> =MIN(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B1)*($C$1:$C$100=$C1)*($D$1:$D$100=$D1)*($F$1:$F$100=$F1),$E$1:$E$100)) [press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (this is an array formula)]

H --> =MAX(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B1)*($C$1:$C$100=$C1)*($D$1:$D$100=$D1)*($F$1:$F$100=$F1),$E$1:$E$100)) [press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (this is an array formula)]

I --> =H1-G1
```

(drag down to expand the formulas to all rows)

It should look like this:

```
A             B          C         D              E       F                              G                              H                              I
04/04/2012    John       186       Workstation    4813    =DATE(YEAR(A1), MONTH(A1), 1)  {=MIN(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B1)...  {=MAX(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B1)...  =H1-G1
04/04/2012    Mary       181       Workstation    2273    =DATE(YEAR(A2), MONTH(A2), 1)  {=MIN(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B2)...  {=MAX(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B2)...  =H2-G2
04/05/2012    John       186       Workstation    4822    =DATE(YEAR(A3), MONTH(A3), 1)  {=MIN(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B3)...  {=MAX(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B3)...  =H3-G3
04/05/2012    Mary       181       Workstation    2274    =DATE(YEAR(A4), MONTH(A4), 1)  {=MIN(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B4)...  {=MAX(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B4)...  =H4-G4
04/06/2012    John       186       Workstation    4854    =DATE(YEAR(A5), MONTH(A5), 1)  {=MIN(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B5)...  {=MAX(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B5)...  =H5-G5
04/06/2012    Mary       181       Workstation    2275    =DATE(YEAR(A6), MONTH(A6), 1)  {=MIN(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B6)...  {=MAX(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B6)...  =H6-G6
04/06/2012    Bill       183       Workstation    3698    =DATE(YEAR(A7), MONTH(A7), 1)  {=MIN(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B7)...  {=MAX(IF(($B$1:$B$100=$B7)...  =H7-G7
```

The result being:

```
A             B          C         D              E       F              G        H        I
04/04/2012    John       186       Workstation    4813    04/01/2012     4813     4854     41
04/04/2012    Mary       181       Workstation    2273    04/01/2012     2273     2275     2
04/05/2012    John       186       Workstation    4822    04/01/2012     4813     4854     41
04/05/2012    Mary       181       Workstation    2274    04/01/2012     2273     2275     2
04/06/2012    John       186       Workstation    4854    04/01/2012     4813     4854     41
04/06/2012    Mary       181       Workstation    2275    04/01/2012     2273     2275     2
04/06/2012    Bill       183       Workstation    3698    04/01/2012     3698     3698     0
```

For clarity's sake, let's get references for the relevant data in another sheet. Assuming the data above is stored in `Sheet1`, enter the following on `Sheet2`:

```
A           B            C           D           E
=Sheet1!F1  =Sheet1!B1   =Sheet1!C1  =Sheet1!D1  =Sheet1!I1
=Sheet1!F2  =Sheet1!B2   =Sheet1!C2  =Sheet1!D2  =Sheet1!I2
...
```

The result being:

```
A             B          C         D              E
04/01/2012    John       186       Workstation    41
04/01/2012    Mary       181       Workstation    2
04/01/2012    John       186       Workstation    41
04/01/2012    Mary       181       Workstation    2
04/01/2012    John       186       Workstation    41
04/01/2012    Mary       181       Workstation    2
04/01/2012    Bill       183       Workstation    0
```

**Finally, on `Sheet2`:**

- [change the format](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformatting/ss/number_format_5.htm) of column ***A*** to "custom" / `mmmm yyyy`, so that the date is displayed as you like (i.e. `April 2012` instead of `04/01/2012`)
- last but not least: [use excel's advanced filter](https://superuser.com/questions/49614/how-do-i-get-the-distinct-values-in-a-column-in-excel/49618#49618) to get rid of the duplicates.